# Using the explode or regex or substr function to extract city out of a state in php

Tags: php, explode

I have the below code where I am trying to extract the city out of a city state string.  It works in most instances, but discovered it does not work in the below due to Colorado being in the city and also being the state.  I need to make `$geography_nav` Colorado Springs and i also need it to work when the state is not part of the city string.  Any idea on how to accomplish this?

`$geography->description = Colorado

     $geography->name- = Colorado Springs Colorado`

```
 $geography_nav=explode($geography->description, $geography->name);</code>
```

I am updating this, I don't necessarly need to use explode, just trying to find some way to extract the city out of the city state string.  The format will always be the same as shown above in `$Geography->name` and the

$Geography->description will always equal the state name.

Comment: Impossible to get right. Ask for a better feed.

Comment: Have you read the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) of explode at least one time? Do you know that there is a PHP manual?

Comment: Is the state always at the end?

Comment: Don't forget Kansas City, Missouri. Unless you've got a complete list of all cities/states to work off, you'll never be able to get an automated extractor going with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @ajon the state is always at the end and it always has a space between the city and state.

Comment: @user1609391 - But a state could be two words, South Carolina, North Dakota - you'd be better using a lookup table of cities and their states

Comment: @Mark Baker, yes that is correct, however the `$geography->description` will always = the state string.  Think it is possible with regex and taking the right of the string somehow?

Comment: @user1609391 IF this is true, see my answer below.

Comment: Could you use `rtrim()`? ie. `$geography_nav=rtrim($geography->name, $geography->description)`

Comment: No, if the city ends with any of the letters in the state, then the cities name would be trimmed, and that would only retrieve the letters of the city that didn't get trimmed.  It wouldn't have the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I utilized the [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function which searches for an instance of a string from the right.

This **will** work if you know that $geography->name definitely has the state that is at the end of $geography->description.

```
$statePos = strrpos($geography->name, $geography->description);
if ($statePos>0){
   $state = substr($geography->description, $statePos);
   $city = substr($geography->description, 0, strlen($geography->description)-$statePos);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this.  It worked but I had to edit your `$city` to `$city = substr($geography->name, 0, $statePos);`

Comment: haha, I was worried about a one off error. I subtracted 1 to remove the space, but forgot that this method goes up to but not including the last index.  Glad it worked.  I changed my code to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess if you have an array of states you could try to do a strrpos() and find the last incidence (if any) of each state name. Explode is not going to do you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a regex here is what you really need.  Use preg_match on each entry
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

regex: `$regex = '/([a-z\s]+)\s[(Arizona),(New Mexico)]/i'`

usage: `preg_match( $regex , $string , $matches ); $city = $matches[1];`

(add all of the states, comma separated and within parens to the square brackets)

**EDIT**

To use the code you provided above:

```
if( preg_match( '/^([a-z\s]+)\s' . $geography->description . '/i' , $geography->name, $matches ) )
    $geography_nav = $matches[1];
```

Comment: edited to fix concatenation, also added string begin delimiter and updated $matches[0] to $matches[1] because [0] is the initial string.

Comment: This solution was tested using the Colorado example and The Missouri City Kansas example.